# Install pgadmin4 on ppc64le Redhat

Tags: pgadmin-4, ppc64le

Is there anyone who has experience on installing pgadmin4 on ppc64le Redhat? I do not find a pgadmin4 rpm package for ppc64le.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't this work? Please try this.

https://opensuse.pkgs.org/15.4/opensuse-oss-x86_64/pgadmin4-4.30-150300.3.3.1.ppc64le.rpm.html

Comment: Thank you, It seems https://opensuse.pkgs.org/15.4/opensuse-oss-x86_64/pgadmin4-4.30-150300.3.3.1.ppc64le.rpm.html is for OpenSuse, is this also good for Redhat?

Comment: yes, I think so